# Adding icon to JLabel in ActionListener on button click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, imageicon

I'm trying to add images that I have already defined in my code to a JLabel, but only when a button has been clicked.

Currently, I've defined the icons as below:

```
    public class Lights extends JPanel implements ActionListener
    {
        public Lights()
        {
            //Dimmable light icons
            ImageIcon dimmable0 = createImageIcon("images/Dimmer0.png");
            ImageIcon dimmable1 = createImageIcon("images/Dimmer1.png");
            ImageIcon dimmable2 = createImageIcon("images/Dimmer2.png");
            ImageIcon dimmable3 = createImageIcon("images/Dimmer3.png");
```

Setting them in this part works fine using

```
    kDimLightLabel = new JLabel(dimmable0);
```

Then when I implement the ActionListener I have a button which will turn the light on, and when it turns on, I want it to set the icon to the dimmable3 icon. At the moment it stands at:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == kLightOn)
    {
        if(Lights[0].getlightStatus() == "Off")
        {
            Lights[0].setlightStatus("On");
            kLightOnOffLabel.setText(Lights[0].getlightStatus());
            kLights.setValue(3); //sets slider as lights go on or off
            dimmableLights[0].setdimLevel(3); //sets array value
            kDimLightLabel.setIcon(dimmable3); //sets label image
        }
    }
```

When I run it, I get 12 errors, all along the same lines for each of the 12 buttons!

kDimLightLabel.setIcon(dimmable3); //sets label image
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable dimmable3
  location: class Lights

Any help as to how to set the icon in the correct manner would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would suggest that the variable `dimmable3` is only available in the scope of the constructor `Lights`. Try making all the `ImageIcon` variables available at class level.

```
public class Lights extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
   private ImageIcon dimmable0; // initialize in constructor
   ...
   public Lights() {
      dimmable0 = createImageIcon(...);
      ...
```

Aside from that, this looks suspicious:

```
if (Lights[0].getlightStatus() == "Off")
```

It would suggest that you have a static `getlightStatus` method for every `Lights` instance. Using a non-static method will ensure that each instance can have it's own individual `lightStatus`. Also use `String#equals` to compare `String` content. The `==` operator is used to compare `Object` references and is *usually* not what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much! It was just because it wasn't declared at class level! As for the second bit, I'll give changing it around and shot and see how it goes! Thanks very much though! :)